How to remove offline emails in Outlook?
I signed out of Outlook because we will be donating the old laptop. I just went to File -> Account -> Sign out and it signed out my device. The problem is, when I load Outlook, although it is requesting for sign-in, I still see some emails on it.
How do I remove these emails? I worry that if I delete the emails, when the laptop connects to the internet, it will also delete the emails in my new laptop.
I read that one option is to go to File -> Account -> Account Settings -> Select account then remove then do the same with Data Files but when I do that, I receive an error. What can I do?


If you are donating the laptop, could you just reset windows to factory instead?

A full secure wipe is best for you, though Windows has a decent Reset option these days, in case you want to leave the computer more functional. You might ask the organization you're donating the computer to whether they have suggestions or guidelines for what you ought to do prior to donating. Regardless, simply deleting some emails is only a small part of what you need to do, and the more thorough and complete methods will take care of that AND the other necessary cleanup things.

@music2myear Yeah. I just did this, we just destroyed the hard disk as per protocol (first time seeing it). Anyway, thank you.
